# Vertical order grid in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the column order only in xs devices with bootstrap
this is what i got

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">column left</div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <div>Column right nro 1</div>
        <div>Column right nro 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to focus on the right column, **only in xs** devices i **need them to be inverted showing first column right nro 2 and then column right nro 1**.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fnkgroove/fhn6b6gb/)

Comment: So you want `column left`, then `nro 2`, then `nro 1`?

Comment: yes, but as i mention, only in xs devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is using display: table and caption-side property and wrap those properties into xs-media rules:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-right {
        display: table;
    }
    .col-right > div:nth-child(2) {
        display: table-caption;
        margin: 0 15px;
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fhn6b6gb/1/

Comment: thanks, it worked. what could be other way to do it?

Comment: This is a very clean and fast way. With CSS there's flexbox, if known heights, absolute positions or negative positive margins and other less elegant approaches than this answer.