# Bootstrap 3 - Change stack order using pull/push?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a stacking col with an image, title and description. On small screen (xs) i want the title to appear over the image and not beneath. Is it possible with bs 3 ?

[Bootply example here](http://www.bootply.com/sbDqyq1Kit)

**html**

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12 red"> Image </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12 blue"> Title </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-12 green"> Description </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

**css**

```
.red { 
    background-color : red;
} 
.green { 
    background-color : green;
} 
.blue { 
    background-color : blue;
}
```

Comment: There are two ways with CSS and one with jQuery. Push and pull work left to right. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27328292/1004312

Comment: possible duplicate of [reorder rows in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311260/reorder-rows-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first sight your question seems very similar to [Possible to achieve this Mobile/Desktop layout using Bootstrap? (or other grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542303/possible-to-achieve-this-mobile-desktop-layout-using-bootstrap-or-other-grid/18547041). But that solution (and the `*-pull-` and `*-push-*` classes) only works when you want to interchange elements in a row which span together a 12 columns width.
In your situation you have two elements which span 12 columns each and have each a width of 100%. Based on [Swap DIV position with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455811/swap-div-position-with-css-only) BS indeed does not offers a solution for your situation.

You can [use jQuery (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698301/is-there-a-native-jquery-function-to-switch-elements) or create a duplicate red row and hide / show that with the [responsive-utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: I though so, Just wanted to make sure i'm not missing anything. I ended up adding two titles one with hidden-sm/lg/md on top and one on the bottom with hidden-xs. Stupid, no doubt, but does the trick.