# Different vertical ordering in mobile and desktop views using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

We need different views in both mobile and desktop which is marked in red color.Since the  right panel has different ordering , position change as absolute and static not working in swtiching landscape (dektop view) and viewport (mobile view). We used jQuery also for calculating the top of the column B and the order is as 1. B and 2. A.  Could you pls help us in resolving this either a bootstrap or normal method?.

Comment: can you add the HTML of what you have currently. this could be done easily with media query of boostrap.. but i dont want to do the whole work for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27328292/1004312

Comment: possible duplicate of [reorder rows in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311260/reorder-rows-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox to rearrange the content of the layout.

I will make something like this:

```
<div id="columns-container">
    <div id="column1">
        Column1
    </div>
    <div id="column2">
        Column2
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the css:

```
columns-container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column; 
}
column1 {
    order: 1;
}
column2 {
    order:2;
}

@media screen 
    and (device-width: 320px) 
    and (device-height: 640px) {
        column1 {
            order: 2;
        }
        column2 {
            order: 1;
        }
   }
```

Other option is use `flex-direction: column-reverse` in the `@media screen` so you will inverse the order of all the columns in the columns-container, but it is easy to maintain and more control of the contained divs if you use the proposed way.