# Change row order for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen several examples on how you can stack the coloumn order in bootstrap by using col-*-push-12, but can you do that to the divs with class container-fluid?

I have the following HTML:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid mydiv1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="container-fluid mydiv2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I use the push classes to reverse the stack order (move mydiv2 up and mydiv1 down) in small devices?

Comment: Why do you have multiple and nested containers? In my experience, one is usually sufficient. Content is then structured and ordered using rows and columns, nesting those if necessary. For example, your structure is probably simplified to this: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/w54fphvy/

Comment: Ah.. you got the point there. If I can manage to include my cols in a single container, I can achieve the result I want. Thanks. Will test and post my results.

Comment: @isherwood Here the problem I faced again. I need to include the container-fluid twice because they both contain different bg colors which I want to fill the screen. I cannot possibly include the bg color css rule to cols because they are nested under container which is positioned in the center with width 1170px. Any workaround you can think of?

Comment: Whoops. Wrong fiddle up there. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ycdcko60/

Comment: Rows, when used properly, fill the width of the screen: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ycdcko60/1/

Comment: Now can you flip the rows when viewed in small devices using push?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reorder rows in bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311260/reorder-rows-in-bootstrap)

Comment: After reading it, I think bootstrap does not support it natively or atleast without some hacks. I will take some more time to read it and monkey my codes again.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the Bootstrap `push`, `pull` classes work in `container-fluid`..

```
<div class="container-fluid mydiv1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-sm-12">
            1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-12">
            2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid mydiv2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
            1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
            2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/5rJqG12KYW)**

Comment: Probably I did not make it clear earlier. What I want is move the whole parent divs up and down.

Comment: What elements, exactly, are the "parent divs"?

Comment: I think she means 'mydiv1', 'mydiv2' containers.